# How can I interpolate bewteen probability distributions?

Tags: distributions, k-nearest-neighbour, interpolation

I would like to implement a nearest-neighbor algorithm. The features are points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the labels I am trying to learn are probability distributions. So the label (probability distribution) of an unknown sample would be the interpolation between the labels of the $k$ nearest neighbors.

Say I have two probability distributions $p_1$ and $p_2$. How can I go about interpolating between these two distributions ?

Comment: To clarify, you have data and know the each point either belongs to p1 or p2? It sounds like a mixed model would fit here if you know what type of distribution they fit. Else a simple k-nearest neighbors with k=2 would work. Sample data/ code would be helfpul.

Comment: The most obvious thing might be to take a weighted mixture.